# Display html in Windows Store app

Tags: c#, .net, html, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am trying to display an html in my Windows Store app (C#/XAML). But I cannot find an appropriate way to display it with the transparent background. Is there any way to get to know app background color and format html for WebView correspondingly? Or shall I better add another page for showing html-description, with setting its background to the one I would like beforehand (in code)? Or maybe there is some better approach?

P.S. I also would like to be able to handle hyperlink clicks, if it's possible. I know I can do so in WebView.

Comment: I presume that you are using XAML / C# ?

Comment: Yes, C#/XAML. I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: Are you trying to display HTML source code or a rendered HTML page?

Comment: Rendered html. I need hyperlinks, formatting, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that WebView controls are actually rendered as a separate surface on top of the XAML layer and consequently do not support transparency. Your best bet would be to do as you suggested: finding the current app background color and setting the WebView HTML's background accordingly.

Getting the app background color is easy; something like `Resources["ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush"]` would do the trick.

Applying that color to whatever page you wish to navigate to is trickier, AFAIK. One method that might work (though I haven't tried it myself) is to use `HttpClient` to download the page's raw HTML and modify the background color prior to calling `WebView.NavigateToString()`, instead of directly calling `WebView.Navigate()`.

If you can edit the page source, you could simplify the process by adding some JS scripts to change the background color, then use `WebView.InvokeScript()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done almost exactly the same thing that you have proposed (downloaded html and then changed the color of the background and foreground manually) already, but have forgotten about that question :-) But that solution does not seem to be a nice way to handle that. I hoped there was a better way to do that :-(